# get the facebook reviews return error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, review

I first get page token with facebook api

```
function createSession($app_id,$app_secret){
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(
    $app_id,$app_secret
    );
    $testUserPermissions = array('user_actions.books','user_actions.fitness','user_actions.music','user_actions.news','user_actions.video','user_birthday','user_games_activity','user_groups','user_hometown','user_interests','user_location','user_relationship_details','user_religion_politics','user_tagged_places','user_videos','user_work_history','read_friendlists','read_page_mailboxes','manage_notifications','read_mailbox','publish_actions','read_stream', 'user_photos','manage_pages','public_profile','user_friends','email','user_about_me','user_activities','user_education_history','user_events','user_likes','user_relationships','user_status','user_website','read_insights','rsvp_event');
    $testUserPath = '/' . $app_id . '/accounts/test-users';
    #$testUserPath = '/100008488695640/accounts/test-users';
    $params = array(
    'installed' => true,
    'name' => 'User test',
    'locale' => 'zh_TW',
    'permissions' => implode(',', $testUserPermissions),
    );
    echo var_dump($params);
    $request = new FacebookRequest(new FacebookSession($app_id . '|' .$app_secret), 'POST', $testUserPath, $params);

    $response = $request->execute()->getGraphObject();
    echo var_dump($response);
    #$testUserId = $response->getProperty('id');
    $testUserAccessToken = $response->getProperty('access_token');
    return new FacebookSession($testUserAccessToken);

}
```

this is my get token

then i use this token to get reviews

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/185342243407/ratings?field=open_graph_story&access_token=$token_value

but it return

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#210) This call requires a Page access token.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 210
   }
}

how i can get the page token?

the token is not used?

Comment: have you find the solution for this please help...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are REALLY using a Page Token. Put the Token in the Debugger and see if it´s a Page Token: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: App ID 817943358271981 : dog
User ID 1404081353236344
Issued Unknown
Expires 1424948400 (15 hours ago)
Valid False
Origin Unknown
Scopes public_profile, basic_info, read_stream, read_mailbox, read_page_mailboxes, rsvp_event, email, read_insights, manage_notifications, read_friendlists, manage_pages, publish_actions, user_birthday, user_religion_politics, user_relationships, user_relationship_details, user_hometown, user_location, user_likes, user_activities, user_interests, user_education_history...       it's show this it not show token type

Comment: does not look like a page token, as i suspected. page tokens include the id of the page.

Comment: and you should really reduce your permissions. a LOT.

Comment: And if you are using a page token but you get this response?

Comment: then you are most likely not really using a page token...what does the debugger say?

Comment: why the downvote? there is no additional info, if you get that error, you are not using a page token, and you need to debug it, period.

Answer (score 0):

When you request multiple permissions, some of them may work with the endpoint you are calling, and some of them may not, causing this 210 error.

In my case, adding `profile_pic` permission to `/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email` caused this error.